# How to call reactJS class function from jquery?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am very beginner in reactJS. Can anybody help me, how to call reactJS class function from my JQuery function.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the react from anywhere you want:

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp/>, $("#root")[0]);
```

It's not usual to combine React with jQuery. Anyway it is possible. Be careful with mixing this two powerful libraries. They work different way.

- Once you'll init some react component don't try to manage the same piece of DOM by the jQuery.